# sentinel vs burrowing and large creatures

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

Would a PC with the Sentinel feat have an opportunity attack against a Bulette which is trying to burrow? If so, would it able to burrow with 0 movement speed (In place in the same square)? Does size make any difference in stopping such a large creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes, given the following in PHB 195:

> The [opportunity] attack interrupts the provoking creature's movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

So, if you can see it trying to burrow and it's within your reach, you hit as it tries to leave, and then it can't move any further.

And no, size makes no difference to Sentinel (features/spells/feats that take size into account mention it explicitly. I.e., Ensnaring Strike agrees with your intuition—it's a spell that attempts to hinder a creature, and anything Large or larger has advantage on the saving throw. As you can see, however, Sentinel doesn't have a similar caveat.)

Comment: What if the Bulette is burrowing straight down? It's still within 5 feet of you nd now it has total cover on the count of being underground.

Comment: If it's adjacent to you, and merely went down 5 feet, I don't think it has **total cover** ("A target has total cover if it is completely concealed by
an obstacle," phb 196) Sure, it's probably *covered* in dirt (in the vernacular sense—sprinkled with dirt, if you will), but still visible and within reach. In my view, any 'cover' it would benefit from would be negated by the tight space it's in (akin to crawling).

Comment: I'll also add that OA is basically designed to punish creatures who try to leave an enemy's reach without Disengaging: if at one point you can see and attack the creature, and it tries to move to avoid being attacked, you get an attack against it, period (i.e., burrowed movement is not an exception to the OA rule). And, with Sentinel, even if they Disengage, and you hit, it can't move anymore.

Comment: If you're taking the creature's height into consideration, yes, 5 feet wouldn't completely bury it underground but neither would it have left the reach of the melee combatant. The Bulette, for example, is a large creature, it fits in a 10x10x10 cube. Only when moving 15 feet straight down does a Bulette leave your reach so you can OA at 10 feet down, at that depth, the Bulette can be totally covered already.

Comment: Again, RAW, the very definition/intent of an OA is to attack a creature attempting to move away *right before* you can no longer attack it. So, at any point when the creature's movement would place it outside your reach, immediately before that happens, you can OA. 

Regarding the details of your scenario: the way I interpret the creature's size vs depth is that, at 10 feet, a Large creature can still be attacked (presumably because it spans the depth of the hole). In other words, it occupies 10 cubic feet, so, no, it would not be totally covered at that depth.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you do not get an attack of opportunity**

Page 195 of the Player's Handbook says the following (emphasis mine):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that **you can see** moves out of your reach.

Having the sentinel feat doesn't change this requirement in any way.

Comment: I suggest you add that Sentinel doesn't mention size, so the answer to OP's last question is also "no."